# Keras - Prediction accuracy of training data is worse?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I've trained my model and got the .hdf5 file. (training and validation accuracy are about 0.9)

Below is my accuracy curve.

[trainnig curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rn5n8.png)

Because of the imbalance of my data, I used SMOTE to oversample my data and then split it into training and validation data.

```
 sm = SMOTE(random_state=42)

X_resampled, y_resampled = sm.fit_resample(X, Y)

X_resampled = X_resampled.reshape(X_resampled.shape[0],128,128,3)

X_tr, X_tst, y_tr, y_tst = train_test_split(X_resampled, y_resampled, test_size=0.33,random_state=22)
```

And below is my model structure.

```
image_input = Input(shape=(img_size, img_size, 3))

conv_1 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), padding='same',
                input_shape=(img_size, img_size, 3), activation='relu')(image_input)
drop_2 = Dropout(0.4)(conv_1)
conv_3 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu')(drop_2)
drop_4 = Dropout(0.4)(conv_3)
max_5 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(drop_4)

conv_6 = Conv2D(32, (5, 5), padding='same', activation='relu')(max_5)
drop_7 = Dropout(0.4)(conv_6)
conv_8 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu')(drop_7)
drop_9 = Dropout(0.4)(conv_8)
max_10= MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(drop_9)

conv_11 = Conv2D(32, (5, 5), padding='same', activation='relu')(max_10)
drop_12 = Dropout(0.4)(conv_11)
conv_13 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu')(drop_12)
drop_14 = Dropout(0.4)(conv_13)
max_15= MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(drop_14)

flat_16 = Flatten()(max_15)

den_17= Dense(8,activation='relu')(flat_16)

output = Dense(nb_classes, activation='softmax')(den_17)

img_size = 128         
nb_classes = 6          
batch_size = 256
nb_epoch=1000
savedModelName = 'M.hdf5'   
lr = 0.00001
```

After I finished training my model, I saved it (by ModelCheckpoint save_best_only according to validation accuracy).

And then I used it to predict the "same" data (same random_state).

```
 sm = SMOTE(random_state=42)

X_resampled, y_resampled = sm.fit_resample(X, Y)

X_resampled = X_resampled.reshape(X_resampled.shape[0], 128, 128, 3)

X_tr, X_tst, y_tr, y_tst = train_test_split(X_resampled, y_resampled, test_size=0.33,random_state=22)
```

But!! I get the prediction accuracy about 0.3.

Why?

Shouldn't it be 0.9?

Answer (score 0):

could you maybe provide the code of you fitting the model.
Also what happens if you predict the first test set with your model? Could you provide maybe a confusion matrix or the Precision/Recall-Values?

My first guess would be, that your model is maybe overfitting or not really learning.

Comment: Add this as a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't provide it right now.
So is it normal when I predict training data and get worse result?
I mean... The training data is already seen by model. Shouldn't it get higher accuracy?

Comment: @rajatkabar I haven't earned the right to comment on others post yet :(

Comment: @DDDAAA I wouldn't say it is normal. But you could say it happens. If you build a model you normaly want it to generalize. Even if you use the same data, if your model can't generalize and doesen't learn anything while training it will have a bad prediction accuracy. But to investigate this futher we would need more info.